# Namespace alias for subnamespaces in local scopes

Tags: c++, namespaces, alias

Consider that I want to call `boost::algorithm::join` as `boost::join`, but I don't want to import the subnamespace in the global namespace as:

```
namespace boost {
   using algorithm::boost;
};
```

Because I want to call `boost::join` with that syntax only in a local scope of an specific function:

```
void my_fun()
{
    namespace boost { // Doesn't allowed syntax in local scope
        using algorithm::join;
    }

    auto ret = boost::join(something...);
}
```

A different approach would be:

```
void my_fun()
{
   using boost::algorithm::join;
   auto ret = join(something...);
}
```

But this would provoke a ADL lookup, and I don't want to do such a lookup, because I know what method I'm calling: `boost::algorithm::join`.

Only, I'm trying to find the shorter `boost::join` way of calling it. What will be the correct syntax or idiom to create a "subnamespace" alias?

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [namespace alias](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias)

Comment: Don't mess with other people's namespaces. You can make your own `namespace boost_misc` or whatever you want to call it, but don't add names to `namespace boost`.

Comment: I don't understand what you have against ADL? It's not something that happens at run-time anyway, only at compilation-time. It's a very simple solution to the problem you have.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Implicit conversions and other possible overloads.

Comment: Are you worried someone else will modify your code, and call the `join` function (in the scope where you have the `using` directive) with arguments that won't be correct? Do you have your own `join` function that might clash with the Boost one? That is active in the same scope as the `using` directive?

Comment: Please improve your question's title, such that it describes the question and has no tags in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this without polluting the Boost namespace, which is not yours to pollute.

Perhaps the following compromise can work for you?

```
namespace balgo = boost::algorithm;
```

Then use `balgo::join`.

So it's not a very descriptive name, but you're trying to make a short alias in a confined scope, right?

Otherwise, the affected region should be small enough that a simple `join` is clear and unambiguous (i.e. `using namespace boost::algorithm`); otherwise, just stick with the fully qualified name. Your team will thank you for it.